# How do I add a cover page in Freemarker?

Tags: html, freemarker, cover

I'm working with Freemarker (mainly to generate quotes from our web-based accounting system). I've figured out headers/footers which work great but what I'd like to do is add a COVER PAGE so that the first page is a cover page, and then the generated quote is below that.

Now I could just throw in some HTML to make it look nice with a bunch of spaces to bring everything down, but I'd like to insert the TITLE from my accounting system's quote on the cover page. My fear is if someone puts in a title that is say 3-4 lines, it'll throw off the look later.

So is there a way I can specify in my code that "this is my cover page"

Comment: Without knowing how you're actually *using* FreeMarker it's impossible to help. FreeMarker is a templating language, it doesn't know what a "cover page" is.

Comment: True... is there a way I can "tell" it "hey this is my cover page, print this first and then print the rest of my documents" ???

Comment: Without knowing how you're actually *using* FreeMarker it's impossible to answer this question. How do you differentiate "pages" at all? What's the output of your transformation? Are you trying to use a single template to perform fundamentally different tasks?

Comment: I actually found it. It's not a freemarker command, it's an HTML command:

<div style="page-break-after:always"></div>

In case anybody is interested, thanks though.